# Having trouble adding a condition to query in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql

I have a record Blocks Realty in my database that is located at 16 miles.

[image: Query results]

```
SELECT x.companyname, x.distance, y.city, y.zip 
FROM (SELECT userid, companyname, lat, lng, 
(3959 * acos(cos(radians(42.323617)) * 
cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-83.200811)) + 
sin(radians(42.323617)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance
FROM users 
WHERE (usertype = 2 OR usertype = 3) 
HAVING distance < 25
order by distance) x 
INNER JOIN 
(select * from users where find_in_set('Real Estate',profession) <> 0) y 
ON x.userid = y.userid
```

When I update the query below to add the city or zip condition and decrease the distance search range, I get the error **#1054 - Unknown column 'city' in 'having clause'**. How do I correct this?

```
SELECT x.companyname, x.distance, y.city, y.zip 
FROM (SELECT userid, companyname, lat, lng, 
(3959 * acos(...) AS distance
FROM users 
WHERE (usertype = 2 OR usertype = 3) 
HAVING distance < 11 
AND (city = 'Detroit' OR zip = '48221') 
order by distance) x 
INNER JOIN 
(select * from users where find_in_set('Real Estate',profession) <> 0) y 
ON x.userid = y.userid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move those conditions to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT x.companyname, x.distance, y.city, y.zip 
FROM (SELECT userid, companyname, lat, lng, 
             (3959 * acos(...) AS distance
      FROM users 
      WHERE usertype IN (2, 3) AND
            (city = 'Detroit' OR zip = '48221') 
      HAVING distance < 11 
      order by distance
    ) x INNER JOIN 
    (select * from users where find_in_set('Real Estate',profession) <> 0) y 
    ON x.userid = y.userid;
```

EDIT:

The reason your original version didn't work is because the `having` clause needs to refer to column aliases defined in the `select`.  So, you can also do:

```
SELECT x.companyname, x.distance, y.city, y.zip 
FROM (SELECT userid, companyname, lat, lng, city, zip
             (3959 * acos(...) AS distance
      FROM users 
      WHERE usertype IN (2, 3)                 
      HAVING distance < 11 OR (city = 'Detroit' OR zip = '48221')
      order by distance
    ) x INNER JOIN 
    (select * from users where find_in_set('Real Estate',profession) <> 0) y 
    ON x.userid = y.userid;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Now I'm only records with Detroit as the city. I need those records to be added to the others with distance less than 11.